# How to change video path into video Uri

Tags: android

In my app I am using Custom Camera to record the video. I am able to do the recording and get the path of video from SD Card as below: `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20141219_133139.mp4`.

Now I want to upload this video on youtube but to uplaod the video I need the path in URI as below : 
`content//media/external/video/media/18576`

Please let me know how can I convert the path to URI.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try to read your own question again and see if you can understand what you mean, edit your question and make it clear what you want

Comment: @AnkitMiglani do you want to change it programatically?? or manually??

Comment: or just wanna change path of recorded video? or change and save it to external media for all recorded video??Please be clear with what you want..make changes to your question accordingly...

Comment: Please Check my question again.

Comment: Do you need absolute path of file from content URI?

Comment: Now it is much Better

Answer (score 0):

```
  content://media/external/video/media/18576
```

means that the video has id=18576 in the media-database. You have to query the media-database for the id. Pseudocode:

```
   select id from 'content//media/external/video/media' 
   where data = '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20141219_133139.mp4'
```

you have to query the media-database

```
// getIdForFile("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20141219_133139.mp4")
public long getIdForFile(String filePath) {
    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        c = this.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Video.Media._ID}, 
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + " = ?",
                new String[]{filePath},
                null              // Default sort order
        );
        if (c.moveToNext()) {
            return c.getInt(0); // MediaStore.Video.Media._ID
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(Global.LOG_CONTEXT, ".... some error message ....", ex);
    } finally {
        if (c != null) c.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Working!

```
 long vidid = getIdForFile(mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
 Log.d("VIDID" , " "+vidid);
 String urivid =  "content://media/external/video/media/"+vidid;
 Uri vid = Uri.parse(urivid); //  it's right uri  for videofile
```

my function getIdForFile

```
public long getIdForFile(String filePath) {
    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        c = this.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Video.Media._ID},
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + " = ?",
                new String[]{filePath},
                null              // Default sort order
        );
        if (c.moveToNext()) {
            return c.getInt(0); // MediaStore.Video.Media._ID
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("VIDURI", ".... some error message ....", ex);
    } finally {
        if (c != null) c.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```